# Firebase Database Rules - getting this error missing ) after argument list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Im getting this error in my firebase realtime database when trying to publish the new rules.The error is as it says in the title "missing ) after argument list" not really sure what the issue is but here is the line that gave me the error
    ,".validate": "newData.val().contains('data.parent().child('Name').val()')"

Comment: Nevermind i found the issue (i had single quotes around data.parent().child('Name').val() as soon as i removed them everything was fine)

Comment: Just curious: are you creating rules using by hand crafting the JSON? If so, have you considered using [bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt)? I've found it to be a very useful tool, once things get even a little complicated.

Comment: I am but i'm very new to firebase i wasn't entirely sure what other options there were ill check it out thanks!!

Comment: Bolt is definitely worth a look. After using it, I cannot imagine hand tooling the JSON rules. The best reference I found was [this one](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/language.md).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes in the value are likely to be the problem:

```
"newData.val().contains('data.parent().child('Name').val()')"
                        ^          these quotes           ^
```